# Erro no push do Navcontroller

Tags: ionic

esta dando erro no push =(( não estou conseguindo fazer a pagina home chamar a pagina Timeline

```js
    import { Component , ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    import { NavController} from '@ionic/angular';
    import { TimelinePage } from "../timeline/timeline";
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
    })
    export class HomePage {

     @ViewChild('Usuario') email;
     @ViewChild('password') senha;

     constructor(public NavCtlr : NavController){ }
     
     entrar(){

       if(this.email.value == "fernando" && this.senha.value == "123"){
 this.NavCtlr.push(TimelinePage);

       }else{

       }
     }
    }
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque seu código; não o print da tela!

Comment: ok vou mudar ...

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao SOpt. Para uma melhoe resposta, tente se expressar melhor. Onde exatamente ocorre o erro, qual o tipo de erro e a descrição  dele? Adicione o máximo  de informações  no post.

Comment: no log esta escrito "property 'push' do not exist on type 'Navcontroller'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está utilizando a versão 4 do Ionic que não possui mais o método `push`. Para navegar entre páginas, você precisa usar o novo método chamado `navigateForward`. Seu uso seria assim:

```
// O 'timelinePage' precisa estar definido no seu app-routing.module.ts
this.NavCtlr.navigateForward('timelinePage');
```

Para saber mais sobre a nova navegação, recomendo esse artigo (em inglês), [acesse aqui](https://www.joshmorony.com/using-angular-routing-with-ionic-4/).